# Is there a way to view all images loaded in the browser using Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I know that I am supposed to be able to see this in the "resources" tab -section of Chrome developer tools.  Maybe I am not getting something,  but I don't see any images listed in this section.

Does anyone know if / how this can be accomplished?

Comment: Have you expanded the "Frames" tree item and drilled down to the frame you need?

Comment: There used to be a nice Firefox extension that would show them as thumbnails. I think it was called Save Tabbed Images.

Answer (score 89):

- Open Google Chrome Console (F12)
- Go to Network tab
- Enable Filter, if it’s not enabled
- Select the "Img" tag to filter for image requests
- **Refresh the page** to see a list of all images as they are requested

[image: see all images loaded with google chrome]

Comment: As a plus: some sites try to make images hard to find/download. Searching also `base64` will help find the desired images

Comment: How can I see the calculated total of all images?

Answer (score 15):

DevTools -> Application tab -> Frames (in the sidebar) -> Images

Contains all the images.

Images are listed specific to each frame. Normally there is only 1 frame on the page. If the page uses the  tag there will be others.

Expand "Frames" and then the first item listed (which is the page), below this is the category of images, as well as scripts and stylesheets. Note that the final item is the html of the page itself.

Comment: No longer exists in 2024

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to use new `resource-type` filter is available in the Network panel (Chrome 87).

For images just type `resource-type:image` to focus on the network requests that are images.

[image]

Chrome Docs: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2020/10/devtools#network-filters

Comment: Could you expand your answer to reflect on why someone would type this rather than clicking the "Img" button to the right of that text box? As in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42587791/506073

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download images :

1. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/download-all-images/ifipmflagepipjokmbdecpmjbibjnakm
2. use site sucker app for mac or httrack website copier windows to get all contetn from page you want then select or sort data how you need ))

Hope i helped you ;)